# How to do raindrop detection for improved image registration on camera vision using CNN?

Tags: object-detection

How to improved
image registration in rainy weather situations.I would like to be able to  detect raindrop and then do raindrop removal using CNN as showing in the image below.

[CLICK Here to view Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXGJu.png)

In this [Paper](http://w.cvlibs.net/publications/Roser2009ICCVWORK.pdf) explained how it can be done but not using CNN.

Please share if you have done similar project. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: that's pretty cool.  where is that image from?  looks like it made a mistake where it thinks the cloud is part of a raindrop.

Comment: @thang This paper explain how its done but not using CNN http://w.cvlibs.net/publications/Roser2009ICCVWORK.pdf

Comment: that's interesting.  it clearly makes a lot of mistakes (i can see 3 very obvious mistakes).... you would think physics based method would be better.  maybe their comparison isn't so good.